# WF 4.5 is it possible to navigate back to a previous activity

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

We need a way to navigate back to a previous activity in a workflow. Is this possible? We are not sure whether we need to backout/undo the current activity or not. Can we use the new bookmark functionality for this?

Comment: Not really.  That's not how WF4 works.  I suggest you [edit] your question, specify your requirements, and describe how you believe they can be satisfied by "navigating back".  That way people with experience with WF4 can suggest ways that this can be implemented using available patterns.  My best guess is that you need what is referred to as a ["flowchart workflow"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489448.aspx), which would loop back to the previous activity if some condition was not met.

Answer (score 1):

As Will stated just use a flowchart or a statemachine workflow. In most cases in which you need to "navigate back", those two might fit better. Flowcharts are able to easily express any kind of algorithm requiring many decisions, whilst statemachines can help you repeat activities unless a specific state has been entered.
I hope this couple of information helped a little :-)

Regards
Jan